# using client server text chat to provide audio support

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I have implemented a multiple client-server text chat in c over Linux(using TCP sockets). Now i want to use it to support audio files as well.After going through stack overflow i found that this can be achieved by sending a file from client to server and server sending same file to all clients.
Now my question is

1. how can the server(and clients) differentiate whether it is receiving ordinary text data or (the server)has to pack the receiving data into a file?
2. Also till now what i have is that client enters text and the server receives it.How can i provide an option to client to send either a file or text.I was thinking of using switch case(like 1 for file ,2 for text) but that is not a good interface?

Comment: HTTP is a text based protocol capable of transferring binary data. You might like to read on how this is done.

Comment: Also you can encode binary data into ASCII (text) by for example using `base64` encoding.

Comment: @alk Also since he is using sockets he is perfectly able to transfer binary data without any sort of conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two questions here.

For 1: You will need to decide how they differentiate text data from file data, by sending extra bytes. One possible scheme is the following:

- For chat messages:

  1. Send the byte 1 (meaning this is a chat message).
  2. Send the message.
  3. Send a `\n`.
- For files:

  1. Send the byte 2 (meaning this is a file).
  2. Send the length of the file, as an 8-byte integer.
  3. Send the file contents.

For 2: That is also up to you. I would suggest that your client works the same way it does already (anything the user types is a chat message) unless the user types a special command, like "/file". If the user types the command, then the client can ask the user for which file to send, and send it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use an industry-standard way of representing different part types. Have a look at [MIME encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). Your normal messages would be in (e.g.) `text/plain`. This is (broadly) how HTTP determines what to do with the byte-stream it receives from the server.